# UIKitCore UICollectionViewFlowLayout invalidateLayoutWithContext crash in background iOS 15

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, crashlytics

Getting this crash in firebase crashlytics, seems to be iOS 15 only and when device is in background state:

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
the invalidation context ((null)) sent to -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout invalidateLayoutWithContext:] is not an instance of type UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext or a subclass

My current theory is the collectionView is trying to update layout when in the background, but I'm unable to reproduce. Has anyone seem this or have any ideas? Thanks!

Update: I have a suspicion now this may be related to the iOS 15 'pre warming' feature?
[image]

Comment: late to comment but your issue seems to be answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309942/diffable-data-source-for-tableview-error-on-ios-13-inconsistent-associations-fo